# Doing Zend Framework 2 tutorial in manual... I was able to get skeleton to load... now just blank

Tags: php, apache, url, zend-framework, frameworks

So I have made it through the album app tutorial in the manual.  Now when I go to `http://localhost` in my browser, I get a blank screen.  I have tried turning on error reporting to see what is going on, and I get nothing still.  I am not sure what else I need to do.  I tried cutting on the cli server which evidently has something to do with error reporting, but I got an error when I tried to paste the code from the manual. says "public/ doesn't exist"  I am very new to Zend Framework 2, and in all honesty this is incredibly confusing.  Any help or advice as to where I should go to try and find out why I'm having a problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the tutorial, you should have a vhost that maps zf2-tutorial.localhost to the public directory. Before going any further you should make sure the skeleton project works. Since you're early along, maybe it's best to just start over.

You can turn on error reporting to the browser at this link: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html